# Copy a directory recursively from a container to host using docker client go library

Tags: docker, go

I want to recursively copy a directory from a container on the host.

I'm new to golang and fully aware about `docker cp` as an alternative but i need to do it via client go library of docker

I was able to copy a file from a container to host, but unable to do so for directories.

Here's what i have till now

```
package main

import (
    "archive/tar"
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"

    "github.com/docker/docker/api/types"
    "github.com/docker/docker/api/types/container"
    "github.com/docker/docker/client"
)

func main() {
    sourcePath := "/test/file.txt"
    destinationPath := "/home/user/"
    cli, err := client.NewClientWithOpts(client.FromEnv)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
        myContainer, err := cli.ContainerCreate(context.Background(), &container.Config{
        Image: "alpine:test",
     }, nil, nil, nil,"")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error(), "error occurred")
    }
    tarStream, _, err := cli.CopyFromContainer(context.Background(), myContainer.ID, sourcePath)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("something went wrong", err)
    }
    tr := tar.NewReader(tarStream)
    if _, err := tr.Next(); err != nil {
            panic(err)
    }

    dst, err := os.Create(destinationPath + "file.txt")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error occurred", err)
    }
    defer dst.Close()

    _, err = io.Copy(dst, tr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error", err)
    }
    cli.ContainerRemove(context.Background(), myContainer.ID, types.ContainerRemoveOptions{})
}
```

But actually i want to copy the whole directory inside the container `/test/` recursively on the host.

Comment: Instead of doing this, can you start the container with a bind-mounted volume so that it writes its output to a directory that exists on the host?  Or, if the principal goal of the process is to read and write host files, possibly Docker's filesystem isolation isn't a good match for it, and you should run the application outside a container?

Comment: bind mount the volume sounds like a good option.
Actually i have a bunch of docker images carrying some artifacts which i need to pull and copy onto the host. This code will run inside a custom kubernetes controller.

Comment: Sorry, you said "host" and "Kubernetes" together...which host exactly, and will it matter if the controller pod gets deleted and recreated on a different node?  Also if this is a Kubernetes context, you probably can't use the Docker API or usefully use `hostPath` volumes, but you could create a PersistentVolumeClaim (maybe via a StatefulSet) and store the containers' persistent content there.

Comment: sorry about the confusion. This controller will run on the host(node) as a systemd service, similar to `kubelet`.
So inside the controller I can call docker APIs and use hostPath, i can even do docker cp, but I was thinking of a golang way of doing it using docker client library, i figured it'd be straightforward but didn't turned out to be.